# flutter firebase list<model> group for counting value

Tags: flutter, dart

so i have a model that show my order that taken from firebase

```
class Order {
  String buyerId;
  String buyerName;
  String price;

  Order({this.buyerId, this.buyerName, this.price});
}
```

and another model that show the report order

```
class ReportOrder {
  String buyerId;
  String buyerName;
  String priceSum;
  String count;

  ReportOrder({this.buyerId, this.buyerName, this.priceSum, this.count});
}
```

and the result that i get from firebase are

```
List<Order> = [
 Order(buyerId:0001, buyerName: Mr.X, price: 20),
 Order(buyerId:0002, buyerName: Ms.Y, price: 20),
 Order(buyerId:0002, buyerName: Ms.Y, price: 20),
 Order(buyerId:0002, buyerName: Ms.Y, price: 20),
]
```

how can i turn it into something like this?

```
List<ReportOrder> = [
 ReportOrder(buyerId:0001, buyerName: Mr.X, priceSum: 20, count: 1 ),
 ReportOrder(buyerId:0002, buyerName: Ms.Y, priceSum: 60, count: 3 ),
]
```

**update:**

i am asking about transform this list on client/flutter/dart and not in firebase cloud function

Comment: you have to do it in your client code

Comment: yes and that is my main question, how to manipulate it in client/dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do is like this.

```
  List<Order> orders = [
    Order(buyerId: "0001", buyerName: "Mr.X", price: "20"),
    Order(buyerId: "0002", buyerName: "Ms.Y", price: "20"),
    Order(buyerId: "0002", buyerName: "Ms.Y", price: "20"),
    Order(buyerId: "0002", buyerName: "Ms.Y", price: "20"),
  ];
  
  List<ReportOrder> list = [];
  
  for(int j = 0; j < orders.length; j++){
    Order order = orders[j];
    for(int i = 0; i <= list.length; i++){
      if(i == list.length){
        list.add(ReportOrder(buyerId: order.buyerId, buyerName: order.buyerName , priceSum: order.price, count: "1"));
        break;
      }
      if(order.buyerId == list[i].buyerId){
        list[i].priceSum = "${int.parse(list[i].priceSum) + int.parse(order.price)}";
        list[i].count = "${int.parse(list[i].count)+1}";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: wow it works, but can you help me explain about if(i == list.length)? why is it checking the index?

Comment: `if(i == list.length)` condition is because when this condition is true, it means it has reached the end of the list after checking the whole list. So it means it didn't find an existing `ReportOrder` with the same `buyerId` in the `list`. So it will add new `ReportOrder` to the list with `count: "1"` because it is the first order with that `buyerId`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: please fix fileds types: `price` and `priceSum` should be `double` and `count` should be `int`.

Since Dart 2.7 you can use extension

```dart
extension ReportOrderList on List<ReportOrder> {
  void putOrSum(Order order) {
    final index = indexWhere((report) => report.buyerId == order.buyerId);
    if (-1 == index) {
      add(ReportOrder(
        buyerId: order.buyerId,
        buyerName: order.buyerName,
        priceSum: order.price,
        count: 1,
      ));
    } else {
      this[index] = ReportOrder(
        buyerId: order.buyerId,
        buyerName: order.buyerName,
        priceSum: this[index].priceSum + order.price,
        count: ++this[index].count,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And then you do not need to care about duplications in your `OrderReport` list:

```dart
  var list = <Order>[
    Order(buyerId: '0001', buyerName: 'X', price: 20),
    Order(buyerId: '0002', buyerName: 'Y', price: 20),
    Order(buyerId: '0002', buyerName: 'Y', price: 20),
    Order(buyerId: '0002', buyerName: 'Y', price: 20),
  ];

  var newList = <ReportOrder>[];

  for (var obj in list) {
    newList.putOrSum(obj);
  }
```

Comment: where should i put this extension? i tried to put it inside streambuilder or inside the ReportOrder model class but this extension is not recognizedable? my dart version is 2.9.1

Comment: It's like a new class, so outside everything... https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods